# Align <h1> and <span> in the same line

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am using `Bootstrap 5` to build a webpage. My `html` code is as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <title>Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid p-1 bg-secondary text-white text-center">
        <h1>Employee details</h1>
        <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-success">2020-21 period</span>    
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I want to make the `<h1>` and `<span>` appear in the same line, rather than one below the other, but am unable to do so. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated code is as below:

```
<div class="container-fluid p-1 bg-secondary text-white d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <h1>Employee details</h1>
  <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-success ms-3">2020-21 period</span>
</div>
```

Explanation:

1. Add class `d-flex` to make `h1` and `span` in same line.
2. Add class `align-items-center` `justify-content-center` to make them center.
3. (Optional) Add margin by class `ms-3` to the `span` div to add space between `h1` and `span`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `row` class  and `col` class like this

```
<div class="container-fluid p-1 bg-secondary text-white text-center">
    <div class="row">
       <h1 class="col-4">Employee details</h1>
          <span class="col-4 badge rounded-pill bg-success">2020-21 period</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is a `display:flex` and `align items: center` which using bootstrap can be done by the following:

```
<div class="container-fluid p-1 bg-secondary text-white d-flex align-items-center">
    <h1>Employee details</h1>
    <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-success">2020-21 period</span>    
</div>
```

Note that if you need a gap between your `span` and your `h1` you either need to give a `margin-right` to your `h1` or `margin-left` to your `span`. If you want your `h1` & `span` to be positioned in the middle of the `div` you need to add `justify-content-center`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid p-1 bg-secondary text-white text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="col-3">Employee details</h1>
        <p class="col-3 offset-1 badge rounded-pill bg-success">2020-21 period</p>
    </div>    
</div>
```

In a `row` there are 12 columns. Change the `col-3` number to increase or decrease the number of columns that you want to fill.

The `offset-1` is the space between the actual column and the previous. The number of the offset works exactly the same.